# Should AntiForgeryToken be inside or outside of the loop?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, antiforgerytoken

We currently has this code

```
@foreach (var market in Model.Markets.Markets)
{
    <li>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "Market", new {marketId = market.Value}, FormMethod.Post, null))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <button class="btn btn-none market-list__item jsSelectMarket">
                <img src="@market.FlagUrl" class="market-selector__market-icon">
                <p class="market-selector__market-text">@market.Text</p>
            </button>
        }
    </li>
}
```

It looks correct, but profiling shows that a lot of CPU time is spent in generating the anti-forgery tokens (basically 20 times per page for this only).

Is there a way to move @Html.AntiForgeryToken() outside of the foreach so it is only called one?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are posting via ajax, then you can keep `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` outside the loop and add it to while sending ajax by reading from `_RequestVerificationToken` hidden field.

Comment: i wrote a bunch and then deleted as... i think ur real problem is this shouldn't be a Post, so no form need so no AntiForgeryToken needed.... just include values in url...pathing and return what ever the post was going to.

Comment: make the button an styled anchor with link that looks the same as the button....

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath great idea, I will try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should go with Ajax. 
You can try with following code for generic method of post

```
function AjaxPostMethod(url, formName, parameters, successCallback) {

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(formName));

    $(formName).validate();
    
    if ($(formName).valid()) {
        var form = $(formName);
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data:
            {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                model: parameters
            },
            success: successCallback,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

**Everything in one go**